# Why is 13 the smaller height dimension of a Graphics?

Tags: graphics, rasterize, system-limitations

It seems that you cannot get a `Graphics` image with a height dimension less than `13`. Trying to draw something and then asking for the `ImageDimensions` of the resulting `Graphics`, you will get three different results, based on the size of the given height.

For example, try to modify the h value in the following code and see the resulting `ImageDimensions` output (try `h=10`, `h=14`, `h=20`):

```
w = 100;
h = 10;
g = Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {w, h}}]}, AspectRatio -> Full, ImageSize -> {w, h}]
ImageDimensions[g]
```

If you specify an `ImageSize` with a height `>= 15` you will get an `ImageDimensions` output coherent with the specified size.

Instead, drawing something having an height `<  15` produces two unexpected results : for `h <= 11` the resulting height dimension is always 13, and for `11 < h < 15`, we get some turbulence, see this plot of the resulting `ImageDimension` for `h` going from 1 to 32:

```
w = 100;  
t = Table[{h,ImageDimensions[Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {w, h}}]}, ImageSize -> {w, h}]][[2]]}, {h, 1, 32}];  
TableForm[Transpose@t, TableHeadings -> {{"ImageSize height", "ImageDimensions height"}, None}]  
ListLinePlot[t]
```

[image]
[image]

Situation doesn't change applying `Options` to `Graphics`. This is a little `Manipulate` to play around with the stated issue:

```
w = 100;
Manipulate[  
 myLine = Graphics[{Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {w, h}}]}  
   , ImageSize -> {w, h}  
   , AspectRatio -> Full  
   , PlotRangeClipping -> plotRangeClipping  
   , PlotRangePadding -> plotRangePadding  
   , ImagePadding -> imagePadding  
   , ImageMargins -> imageMargins  
   ];  
 h1 = ImageDimensions[myLine][[2]];  
 Column[{  
   Grid[{{"Height:", h}, {"Dimension:", 
      If[h1 == h, Style[h1, Green], Style[h1, Red]]}}],  
   myLine  
   }]  
 , {{h, 1}, 1, 32, 1}  
 , {plotRangeClipping, {False, True}}  
 , {{plotRangePadding, None}, 0, 20, 1}  
 , {imagePadding, 0, 20, 1}  
 , {imageMargins, 0, 20, 1}  
 ]
```

[image]

The problem (bug?) is not with `ImageDimensions` itself, but with `Graphics`, that always add a unwanted surrounding space to its output when vertical size is less than `15`. Here `ImageDimensions` is used just to give numeric evidence to the stated problem.

I notice this behavior in all 10.x releases, also the last one (10.3.0.0), so it seems possible but improbable that this can be a bug passed unnoticed/unresolved until now, maybe I'm missing to set some (unobvious) parameters, any hints?

Comment: The usage of `ImageDimensions` with a general *graphic* is actually not documented, however I get basically the same threshold issue with `ImageDimensions@Image@myLine`.   What are you trying to do? You can get the graphic dimensions with `PlotRange/.AbsoluteOptions[graphic]`

Comment: Thank you George2079, but actually my need isn’t to obtain the dimension of a _Graphic_ by _ImageDimensions_, in my post the usage of ImageDimensions is just to put in evidence the problem (bug?) in _Graphics_. My need is to draw some _Graphics_ elements that are smaller than 13 in vertical size, and then put them together in a _Column_. But as the _Graphics_ output is always filled with the unwanted, unexpected surrounding space when their vertical size is less than 15, these elements result spaced instead to be at the right distance between them.

Comment: I think the issue here relates to rasterization (It appears `ImageDimensions` is implicitly rasterizering to get your number ).  You might want to pose the *column* issue as a new question.

Comment: @Guido, Based on your last comment, are you aware that `ImageSize` is not specified in inches? Per the docs you need to multiply image size by 72 to get inches. 13/72nds of an inch is pretty small for a plot.

Comment: Just for the record, I just tested your code on Mathematica 8.0 (Linux), and there the minimum seems to be 12, and the only anomaly is at `ImageSize` height 12 where the value is 13 instead of 12.

Comment: @george2079 I think you are right, after some other test it seems that it is not *Graphics* itself that adds the extra vertical space, but it is *Rasterize* to doing so when the height of a *Graphics* is less than 15.

Comment: I traced this through various internal functions including ``System`ConvertersDump`iRasterize``, ``System`ConvertersDump`ToRasterDataPacket``, ``System`ConvertersDump`ConvertGraphicToRasterDataPacket``, ``System`ConvertersDump`createExportPacketExpr``, ``System`ConvertersDump`GetRasterData``, and finally ``System`ConvertersDump`Utilities`GetFromFE``.  I was unable to find the source of the minimum raster size despite a few promising dead-ends like ``System`ConvertersDump`PadRaster``.  This appears to be a property of the Front End itself.